# Manually build a model attribute to submit to a spring controller

Tags: javascript, spring, forms, form-data, modelattribute

I need submit a object to this controller:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/insert_pedido", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public String insert_pedido(@RequestParam("cliente") Integer cliente_id, @ModelAttribute("pedido") Pedido pedido) throws JsonProcessingException {
...
  }
```

through a javascript function like that:

```
function insert_pedido(e) {
  var cliente = e.dataset.cliente;
  var pedido = ?
  var url = e.dataset.url;

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", url_pedido, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
...
    }
  };
  formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("cliente", cliente);
  formData.append("pedido", pedido);
  xhr.send(formData);
}
```

I need build the data the controller will be reading by `@ModelAttribute("pedido") Pedido pedido` in the variable `pedido`. Is this possible? If so, how I could do that?

the fields need to be added to this object are:

```
        <div class="form" id="inner-form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="transactionId">transactionId</label>
            <input type="text" name="transactionId" class="form-control" id="transactionId">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="metodoPagamento">metodoPagamento</label>
            <input type="text" name="metodoPagamento" class="form-control" id="metodoPagamento">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dataCompra">dataCompra</label>
            <input type="date" name="dataCompra" class="form-control" id="dataCompra">
          </div>

          <input th:if="${command}" type="hidden" name="cliente" th:value="${command.id}">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="produtos">produtos</label>
            <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="produtos" name="produtos">
              <option th:each="option : ${produtos}" th:value="${option.id}" th:text="${option.nome}"></option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**UPDATE**

I try this:

```
  var pedido = new FormData();
  pedido.append('transactionId', document.getElementById('transactionId').value);
  pedido.append('metodoPagamento', document.getElementById('metodoPagamento').value);
  pedido.append('dataCompra', document.getElementById('dataCompra').value);
  pedido.append('produtos', document.getElementById('produtos').value);
```

which I persistig an entity `pedido` on the database, but with all the fields empty.

Even in the javascript code, if I add this:

```
  console.log(' transactionId: '+document.getElementById('transactionId').value);
  console.log(' metodoPagamento: '+document.getElementById('metodoPagamento').value);
  console.log(' dataCompra: '+document.getElementById('dataCompra').value);
  console.log(' cliente: '+document.getElementById('cliente').value);
  console.log(' produtos: '+document.getElementById('produtos').value);
```

only the fields `dataCompra` and `cliente` are getting the correct values. The others are getting `null` value. All with the html above.

Comment: So is it not working? I don't understand Spanish, but for insert, I don't know why you need to pass an id as request parameter. Also you want to send this as stringified json to the backend as this is what it seems to process on the model.

Comment: the fields are not inside a `form` tag, but inside a `div`. in the javascrtip code I need somehow build a structure which should be read by the parameter `@ModelAttribute("pedido") Pedido pedido` in the controller

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I worked with Spring, but something like this should work:

```
@PostMapping(
  value = "/insert_pedido", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public String insert_pedido(@RequestBody Pedido pedido) {
    return pedidoService.insert(pedido);
}
```

For the client js, you will sadly need to get the json model from the DOM manually (since you're not using a form or model defined in JS that you apply to a template ==> although this is what I'd suggest you to do anyway).

Then you just perform the ajax call

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance 
xmlhttp.open("POST", "/insert_pedido");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ ... })); // => Your json object here
```

Also check the properties on your Java objects (getters and setters) or use a plugin like lombok.
Although it's sort of ugly, your last edit does indeed the manual dom crawling. Check that all your values are properly retrieved and sent over the network (e.g. Chrome network tab).

Comment: Is there a way to do that without json? I try the option I add in the question (see the update), and it's persisting an entity in the database, but several fields are keeping empty.